# collect information from one sheet and place it to a different sheet in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have two excel sheets in the same workbook. sheet1 and sheet2.
in sheet1 i generate dates for each month. for example column z1 will be 3/1/2017, AA1 will be 3/2/2017, AB1 will be 3/3/2017 etc. till the end date of a month.

Then in sheet2 i have some numbers in column N,O,P. every day these numbers could be different.

In column C of both sheet1 and sheet2 are SN stored.

Now I am trying to collect the values from column N,O,P from sheet2 (N+O+P), and store them in sheet1 in column that head = Date   by the same SN.
i am trying to use the following code but this does not work.

could anyone help me with this

```
Sub registrereren()
Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim LastDate As Date
Dim NextDate As Date
Dim r As Long

Dim j As Long
Dim lastrow1 As Long

FirstDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)
LastDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 0)
lastrow1 = Sheets("Registration").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For r = 27 To LastDate

If Cells(1, r) = Date Then
 Next r

   For j = 2 To lastrow1

   Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, r).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & j).Value * 1, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2 : P3000"), 11 + 12 + 13, 0)


    Next j
 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How/why doesn't it work? Does it give an error, if so what error where? FYI you should be sure to specify what sheet you want `Rows.Count` to run on, like you do with `Range()`: `Sheets("Registration").Range("C" & Sheets("Registration").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` Also, to clarify, if `Cells(1,r)` *doesn't* equal `Date`, then you want what to happen? Your loop there I believe is a little out of order. Because, if I understand, it'll only run ONCE `if Cells(1,27)` doesn't equal `Date`, then you're going to go to the end of the sub, is that what's happening? Step through with `F8` to check.

Comment: Hi Bruce. Thank you for your reply. I get an error on the line for Next r  and it says Next without for.   I am not really that advance with VBA. i want to run row.count on both sheet1 and sheet2. I want the first loop to check the first row in sheet1. and then when it finds the head that is equal to date. then i want to collect the information from column N,O,P in sheet2 and paste them in the column that has a eader that is equals to Date.

Answer (score 0):

The `Next r` is misplaced. It should be after the `End If`

The resulting code looks like this:

```
Sub registrereren()
    Dim FirstDate As Date
    Dim LastDate As Date
    Dim NextDate As Date
    Dim r As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lastrow1 As Long

    FirstDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)
    LastDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 0)
    lastrow1 = Sheets("Registration").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For r = 27 To LastDate
        If Cells(1, r) = Date Then
            For j = 2 To lastrow1
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, r).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & j).Value * 1, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2 : P3000"), 11 + 12 + 13, 0)
            Next j
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

The VBA editor makes it easy to indent code. Whenever you start a sub, function, loop, select case, or if statement, get in the habit of indenting the next line by hitting the tab key. When you are done with the block, use the backspace key to get you back to the previous levels of indentation. Furthermore, there are options on the editor ribbon which allows you to indent or dedent whole blocks of code.

Once you get in the habit of doing this, it should jump out at you when a block isn't terminated the correct way. On the other hand, your sporadic and inconsistent indentation made it hard to perceive what was the problem with `Next r`.

The above code compiles, but I wasn't able to test it in any easy way since I'm not sure how your spreadsheet is laid out. If it still doesn't work, you have another problem with the code and could either edit your question or perhaps ask another question if you need to (once you isolate what the problem is).

Comment: Hi John Thank you for your response.

Comment: What I am trying to do is actually like this:                                           Sub test()

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 12).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Sheet2!RC:RC[2])"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A49"), Type:= _
        xlFillDefault
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:A49").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-18
    ActiveCell.Select
End Sub

Comment: I need that the code searches in the first row to find the cell that contains the current Date. and then in this macro the destination should select from that cell to last row.